# Can someone tell me what this statement does?

Tags: python

Input :

```
>>> a.strip().split()
['0-0', '0-1', '0-2', '0-3', '0-4', '0-5', '0-6', '0-7', ...]
```

The statement is:

```
>>> alignment = set([tuple(map(int, x.split("-"))) for x in a.strip().split())
>>> alignment
set([(7, 3), (20, 25), (16, 9), (19, 4), (17, 20), (7, 25), ...])
```

Comment: `alignment` is a set of tuples of integers, where the integers are the numbers separated by "-" in the strings which are in the list produced by `a.strip().split()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a.strip().split()` produces a list of strings of the form `'a-b'` where the `a` and `b` are composed of digit characters.

This means that:

```
alignment = set([tuple(map(int, x.split("-"))) for x in a.strip().split())
```

produces a `set` from a list defined by a list comprehension. The list comprehension takes each of these `'a-b'` strings, spits it into two on the `'-'` character and then converts each of those from string to integer value by `map`ping the `int` function onto them, and then lastly converts the resulting pair into a tuple of two integer values — this results is a `set` being produced from a list of tuples -- which is the result you're seeing.